# CUDA: thrust::sort_by_key does not work in the kernel, but thrust::sort does

Tags: sorting, cuda, thrust

I am trying to move some of my existing `thrust::sort_by_key` calls to kernel threads. These are large numbers of small sorts - so lots of threads running sequential sorts makes a lot of sense.

`thrust::sort` appears to work fine in the kernel, eg:  (xp is a float*; beg & en are integer indices)

```
thrust::sort( thrust::seq, xp+beg, xp+en);
```

Original on my host-side code I was using a `thrust::zip_iterator`. Porting that to the kernel didn't seem to work, so I tried to create my own index array:

```
int*pIDX = new int[en-beg]; // inefficient: eventually this would be a global workspace

for (int i=0; i<en-beg; i++)
    pIDX[i] = i;

thrust::sort_by_key( thrust::seq, xp+beg, xp+en, pIDX);
```

Trying this produces a "unspecified launch failure (719)" at the next cudaMemCpy call.
Tracing with the debugger causes a terminate at `thrust::sort_by_key` but with no message.

Searching the web and this site suggests `sort_by_key` should work in a kernel if I explicitly tell it to work sequentially. So any thoughts as to what might be wrong?

Comment: according to my testing, your method works fine.  For questions like this, SO expects you to provide a [mcve] as indicated in item 1 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  I also suggest you provde the platform you are running on (GPU, host OS) and the CUDA version you are using.

Comment: it's entirely possible that if you are doing this on a large scale (many threads/large data) that you are running into the limits on device heap, see [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#dynamic-global-memory-allocation-and-operations) read the whole section, carefully.   In-kernel `new` has identical characteristics to in-kernel `malloc()`.   To rule this out, test the returned pointer from `new` for NULL and do something appropriate.

Comment: For testing this is only one thread. The heap has also been expanded a lot for other reasons. new is returning a non-null.  CUDA 7.5, Ubuntu.

Comment: GeForce RTX 2080.  1168MB

Comment: [Here's](https://pastebin.com/UpFF5Kbc) my 1-thread test case.  It seems to work fine.  CUDA 10.2, CentOS 7, Tesla V100.  If you are actually using CUDA 7.5 (not sure why you would do that) that may be the issue.  CUDA 7.5 is like, 5 years old.

Comment: Thanks - that was useful, and running with a small number. I've found teh problem: Yes the heap, but not my new, it was in the actual sort_be_key. I'll write an answer explaining more.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. Yes it was a heap problem, but not in the temporary `new` in the code, it was in `sort_by_key` itself. Extending the heap caused the problem to go away. For some reason `sort` does not need as much heap as `sort_by_key`.

On a whim I tried `zip_iterator` and that also appears to work now (the abstraction simplifies my code!).

For this test I was working with 9.7M floats in `xp`. The wider problem has a small number of large sorts and a large number of small sorts - for this dataset the biggest sort is 9.7M but they can go all the way down to 2 values. I have thrust's parallel sort working fine, but this is far too inefficient for the small sorts, so the plan is to switch to my own kernel for these - running lots of small sorts on parallel threads. So, once this is fully implemented it should be possible to bring the heap size down again.